# Matlab: fmincon throws error

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am implementing the expression given in the image which is the log-likelihood for AR(p) model.
[image: Log likelihood]

In this case, `p=2`. I am using `fmincon` as the optimization tool. I checked the documentation and  other examples over internet regarding the syntax of this command. Still, I am unable to mitigate the problem. Can somebody please help in eliminating the problem?

The following is the error

```
Warning: Options LargeScale = 'off' and Algorithm = 'trust-region-reflective' conflict.
Ignoring Algorithm and running active-set algorithm. To run trust-region-reflective, set
LargeScale = 'on'. To run active-set without this warning, use Algorithm = 'active-set'. 
> In fmincon at 456
  In MLE_AR2 at 20 
Error using ll_AR2 (line 6)
Not enough input arguments.

Error in fmincon (line 601)
      initVals.f = feval(funfcn{3},X,varargin{:});

Error in MLE_AR2 (line 20)
   [theta_hat,likelihood] =
   fmincon(@ll_AR2,theta0,[],[],[],[],low_theta,up_theta,[],opts);

Caused by:
    Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. FMINCON cannot
    continue.
```

The vector of unknown parameters,

```
theta_hat = [c, theta0, theta1, theta2] where c = intercept in the original model which is zero ; theta0 = phi1 = 0.195 ; theta1 = -0.95; theta2 = variance of the noise sigma2_epsilon.
```

**The CODE:**

```
     clc
    clear all
    global ERS
    var_eps = 1;
    epsilon = sqrt(var_eps)*randn(5000,1); % Gaussian signal exciting the AR model
    theta0 = ones(4,1);  %Initial values of the parameters
    low_theta = zeros(4,1); %Lower bound of the parameters
    up_theta = 100*ones(4,1); %upper bound of the parameters
    opts=optimset('DerivativeCheck','off','Display','off','TolX',1e-6,'TolFun',1e-6,...
   'Diagnostics','off','MaxIter', 200, 'LargeScale','off');
    ERS(1) = 0.0;
    ERS(2) = 0.0;
    for t= 3:5000
    ERS(t)=  0.1950*ERS(t-1) -0.9500*ERS(t-2)+ epsilon(t); %AR(2) model y
    end


   [theta_hat,likelihood,exit1] = fmincon(@ll_AR2,theta0,[],[],[],[],low_theta,up_theta,[],opts);

exit(1,1)=exit1;

format long;disp(num2str([theta_hat],5))


function L = ll_AR2(theta,Y)
rho0 = theta(1); %c
rho1 = theta(2); %phi1
rho2 = theta(3); %phi2
sigma2_epsilon = theta(4);
T= size(Y,1);
p=2;
mu_p = rho0./(1-rho1-rho2); %mean of Y for the first p samples
%changed sign of the log likelihood expression    
cov_p = xcov(Y);
L1 = (Y(3:end) - rho0 - rho1.*Y(1:end-1) - rho2.*Y(1:end-2)).^2;
 L = (p/2).*(log(2*pi)) + (p/2).*log(sigma2_epsilon) - 0.5*log(det(inv(cov_p))) + 0.5*(sigma2_epsilon^-1).*(Y(p) - mu_p)'.*inv(cov_p).*(Y(p) - mu_p)+...
     (T-p).*0.5*log(2*pi) + 0.5*(T-p).*log(sigma2_epsilon) + 0.5*(sigma2_epsilon^-1).*L1;
L = sum(L);
end
```

Comment: 1. don't use `exit` as a variable name - it's a function name. 2. the function `ll_AR2` should have only one input `theta`, what is `Y` there? `fmincon` calls `ll_AR2` with only its internal `theta` it does not hold `Y`.

Comment: @Shai: Should I not pass the data vector which is Y? If I don't then how will the function ll_AR2 evaluate without the data.

Comment: is `Y` fixed through the optimization? where is it defined?

Comment: Y variable is passed in the function argument ll_AR2. In the main script I have used the variable ERS to represent the AR model whose parameters I would like to optimize/estimate. Y is fixed.

Comment: then what you need is to call `fmincon` with the following function: `fmincon( @(theta) ll_AR2(theta, Y), theta0, [],[],[],[],low_theta,up_theta,[],opts);` make sure `Y` is defined before you call `fmincon`.

Comment: see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/writing-objective-functions.html#brhkghv-6) for more info.

Comment: and also [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/passing-extra-parameters.html#brhkghv-9).

Comment: @Shai: So, that error is gone! Thank you. But, a new error Error using  - 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in ll_AR2 (line 12)
L1 = (Y(3:end) - rho0 - rho1.*Y(1:end-1) - rho2.*Y(1:end-2)).^2; This is probably due to the last term in the log-likelihood expression which I have implemented in the variable L1. Could you please have a look at this? Thank you for your effort and time.

Comment: please use debugger and see the dimensions of your variables. Is it possible that you want `rho1.*Y(2:end-1)` instead of `rho1.*Y(1:end-1) `?

Comment: I am having difficulty in representinh y(t-1) and y(t-2) in index notation. For, y(t-1) I did Y(1:end-1) and for y(-2) = Y(1:end-1). Based on your comments, is y(t-1) = Y(2:end-1)?

Comment: I am not sure, but you must have all components of the expression for `L1` with the same number of elements.

Comment: (Rolled back another substantial edit that removed code etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass constant parameters to the objective function (`Y`) in addition to the optimization variables (`theta`).
The right way of doing so is using anonymous function:

```
 Y = ...; %// define your parameter here
 fmincon( @(theta) ll_AR2(theta, Y), theta0, [],[],[],[],low_theta,up_theta,[],opts);
```

Now the objective function, as far as `fmincon` concerns, depends only on `theta`.

For more information you can read about [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/writing-objective-functions.html#brhkghv-6) and [passing const parameters](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/passing-extra-parameters.html#brhkghv-9).